# Azure Management API produces 403 error

Tags: c#, rest, api, azure

I'm trying to use the Azure Management API to get metrics data.  However it is throwing a 403 exception.  Does anyone have any idea why this code wouldn't work?  I feel this code is pretty simple and is based on the MSDN article but still throws a 403.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
    private string GetAccessToken()
    {
        var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(string.Format("https://login.windows.net/{0}", TenantID));
        var credential = new ClientCredential(clientId: AppID, clientSecret: SecretKey);
        var result = authenticationContext.AcquireToken(resource: "https://management.core.windows.net/", 
            clientCredential: credential);

        if (result == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to obtain the JWT token");
        }

        string token = result.AccessToken;
        return token;
    }
```

...

```
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            string header = GetAccessToken();

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(
    "Bearer", header

    );

            if (! resourceID.StartsWith("/"))
            {
                resourceID = "/" + resourceID;
            }

            string url = "https://management.azure.com" + resourceID +
                "/providers/microsoft.insights/metricdefinitions?api-version=2016-03-01";
            var response = client.GetStringAsync(url).Result;

            return response;
        }
```

Comment: I believe there should be a space after "Bearer" in `new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", header)` i.e. it should be "Bearer ". Please give it a try and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: Do you have any updates about this thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a try to create the service principal and assign the corresponding role to the service principal. We can create it easily using PowerShell. More Info about how to get access token please refer to the [article](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_stranger/2016/10/21/using-the-azure-arm-rest-apin-get-access-token/).

```
New-AzureRmADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId $app.ApplicationId

New-AzureRmRoleAssignment -RoleDefinitionName Contributor -ServicePrincipalName $app.ApplicationId.Guid
```

As I have no metricdefinitions info in the resource, when I try to get metric info then I get 404 error. While I try another API `/providers/microsoft.insights/alertrules?api-version=2016-03-01` . It works correctly for me.

[image]